# Getting 3rd level descendant in nested table

Tags: css, html, jquery-selectors, css-tables, nested-table

I have an HTML page with tables nested to the 3rd level. I need help with a jquery selector to select the 3rd descendant table. Please note the topmost table has an id of "mytable" but the nested ones have no id. Clarifying again: this is the 3rd level nested table I want to pick and not a sibling table.

Answer (score 0):

How does this work for you?

```
$('#mytable > table > table > table')
```

Comment: doesn't seem to be working but no error in my console. might be my code, will look closer. Thx